# Saving a list of a public Github repo contributors using curl

Tags: github, curl

I'm trying to get a list of contributors to a public GitHub repo, saved as a text file.

```
curl -H "Authorization: token mytoken" https://api.github.com/repos/v2fly/v2ray-core/contributors&per_page=100 >> output.txt
```

I get the output in the terminal, but not to the file. Also, the request doesn't seem to close. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the API URL is incorrect. That `per_page` querystring needs to be passed after putting "?" after URL, You can try this

```
curl -H "Authorization: token mytoken" https://api.github.com/repos/v2fly/v2ray-core/contributors?per_page=100 >> output.txt
```